# Object Input Stream Class cast exception - even though it shouldn't happen

Tags: java, sockets, networking

i have a weird problem. I am trying to write simple Client - Server app with chat option, but i ran into a problem - Object Input Stream reads wrong class. Error is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.oxomoco.packets.PacketAlive cannot be cast to org.oxomoco.packets.PacketMessage
at org.oxomoco.server.SocketConnectionServer.run(SocketConnectionServer.java:52)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And it happens here:

```
 PacketMessage pm = (PacketMessage)ois.readObject();
```

Which is in loop that looks like this:

```
            while(true){




            //if(ois.readObject() instanceof PacketMessage){


            //  pm = (PacketMessage)ois.readObject();
            //  se.println(ois.readObject().toString());
            //}



            if((ois.readObject() instanceof PacketMessage)==true){
                System.out.println("It is: " + (ois.readObject() instanceof PacketMessage));

                PacketMessage pm = (PacketMessage)ois.readObject();

                se.acprintln(">>",uname + ": " +pm.getMsg());

            }
            if((ois.readObject() instanceof PacketAlive)==true){
                System.out.println("-it is: " + (ois.readObject() instanceof PacketAlive));
                PacketAlive pa = (PacketAlive)ois.readObject();
            }

    }
```

Somehow - even though i check instances - Object input stream is instance of PacketMessage when it should be instance of PacketAlive. Does anyone have an idea why, and of course - how to fix it?

Comment: Not to be crass, but is this opposed to those exceptions that should happen? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're executing

```
ois.readObject()
```

several times, and getting a different object (of a different class?) *each time*. `readObject()` *pulls* each object from the stream, rather than leave it there.

Instead, read it, assign to a variable and then perform your tests etc. e.g.

```
while (true) {
   Object obj = ois.readObject();
   // do something with obj...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try assigning the return value of ois.readObject() to a variable, rather than calling it twice.

Each time you call readObject you are consuming more bytes from the stream, it won't give you the same object back each time.